# Launch URL with quotes from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm currently writing a powershell function that (in the end, hopefully) will function identically to Google's advanced search in order to help teach myself scripting.  Using [this blog article](https://moz.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters) I was able to put most of the functionality together, but noticed that when trying to 'start' a url with quotes in it, it doesn't function the way I expect it to.

For example, when I put the following in powershell:

```
start "http://google.com/search?&as_q=hi&as_oq=`"there+how+are`"+you"
```

Chrome will launch with the url without the "'s around 'there+how+are'.

If I put the URL in manually, without the gravemarkers, it works as expected.

I'm on Windows 10.  My default browser is google chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Not certain (hence comment, not answer), but I think you can do `start --% "http.....`. The --% tells PS to stop parsing the remainder of the command.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I think it's causing Powershell to stop recognizing that the enclosed value is a url and needs to be launched in a web browser.  I also tried using `start chrome.exe --% "url"` and that didn't seem to work either; however, I think I may have found a potential workaround that answers my question, which I will post below.

Answer (score 3):

One can use url encoding for special characters - i.e. `%20` is equivalent to having a single space in the url.  It turns out `%22` is equivalent to double quotes.  See [this w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for a large list of url encodings.

With that information, it follows that this command does the trick:

```
start "http://google.com/search?&as_q=hi&as_oq=%22there+how+are%22+you"
```